# changing a global variabile inside a fucntion in Python code step by Zapier

Tags: zapier

I have this simple python code:

```
x = 10
def myfunc():
    global x
    x=15
       
myfunc()



output = [{'id': x, 'hello': ""}]
```

The output is 10 instead of 15. Any idea on how can I change a global variable inside a function  when using a python Code step by Zapier

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.

This issue also took me a lot of time to debug my codes that run well locally but fail in Zapier. I guess Zapier actually wrap our codes in some way - maybe put our codes inside a big function and Zapier calls this function to run our codes. So those global variables are no longer really global in this environment.

I tried a few ways and all of them didn’t work.
I got a conclusion that **“We can NOT modify a global variable in our Zapier codes. We can only read a “global” variable – which is not really global
in Zapier's environment”**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I guess we can't have complex functions running inside a zapier code step. So we have to stick to small functions or loops. 

Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the best way to deal with this is to use a Webhook Step to pass the info out to Google Cloud Functions (or an AWS/Azure equivalent). This will let you run whatever you like + import Python libraries that Zapier will not let you use.

Cloud Functions is pretty simple, I was able to figure it out as a marketing dude with no coding background beyond the Zapier code steps.

This way you can just pass the result back to Zapier. I also find it makes debugging easier as the Zapier interface can be a bit cumbersome when you are  repeatidly retesting something.